# Jackson mapper to persistence object

Tags: java, junit, jackson

I writing  JUNIT for a very complex hierarchy application 
I need to test a service that his input is a very large and complicated persistence object.
As it so big it we decided to initialize it with JSONN string.
The problem is that because  it has a large Inheritance tree its getting very difficult to Jackson to de serializing  it.
is there a why to instruct Jackson by annotation that he will not do automatic serializing and just will do explicit.
I want to ignore all filed and getters/setters  except the one that with @JsonProperty annotation

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using the following config

```
getMapper().setVisibilityChecker(getMapper().getDeserializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```